# What is the boundary from N to S called in magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology

I am doing some research on asymmetric magnetic fields. I have simplified my problem to an isosceles triangle mangnetized with the N side on the tip with the smallest angle and the S side opposite of it. I am attempting to determine where the boundary from N to S will be and the curvature (if any) of that line.

[image: isosceles triangle]

I am having difficulty because I do not know the terminology. Is there a word for this boundary?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "boundary"? I suspect there's no term for the boundary because there *is* nothing like a boundary in this context (except the surface of the material, of course).

Comment: It would help if you could put an N and an S in the picture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "boundary" between north and south, because there is no magnetic charge (i.e., the fundamental unit of magnetic field is a dipole field). Put another way, if you break a bar magnet at any one point along its length, you will get two new magnets, each with its own north and south end, so there is no place where you can draw a "boundary" where the stuff on one side is north and the other side is south,

Comment: Further to @march comment above, each individual atom also has a north and south pole, so you could continue to cut the magnet in half until you are down to a single atom, and you would still have a magnet.

Comment: If N and S are not equal then there must be a boundary between them. If there is no vocabulary word for this, then that is my answer. I am asking if there is a word to describe the magnetically neutral "line" between the poles, regardless of the size of the magnet.

Comment: I don't know if there's a formal definition of what "magnetic poles" are, but I would expect them to be _points_ on the surface. The field surrounding a simple (two pole) permanent magnet resembles a [_dipole_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole) if you look at it from far enough away, and as far as I know, the "poles" are the locations on the surface of the magnet where the axis of that dipole passes through. But, what you are asking for (if not "poles," then _what?_ I don't know!) are the regions of the surface where the field lines either point inward (North) or outward (South)...

Comment: ...and specifically, you are asking for a name for the boundary between those regions. (Sorry, but I can't answer that either.)

Comment: There is a type of thing referred to as a [domain wall](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_wall_(magnetism)) of which there are varieties. Though it doesn't exactly fit your description, perhaps you mean that?